# Video lag in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: 20.04, firefox, google-chrome, video

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 and noticed that in Chrome or Firefox video is lagging. It doesn't matter if video is being played in YouTube, Twitter, Facebook, the result is same - lag. Any advice?

My laptop is Lenovo y580. The laptop specifications are:

- CPU - i7
- GPU - Nvidia 660
- RAM - 6GB

P.S. I have already installed NVIDIA driver, but video is still lagging.

Comment: Provide the output of `inxi -SG`. Did you try to `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`?

Comment: is the widevine browser plugin/extension installed and updated? is hardware acceleration enabled? does video playback stutter in a media player (like VLC) or is it just in web browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I had/have a very similar problem as what you describe.
Or maybe not exactly the same, I'm not so sure from your description.
In my case, the video would completely hang. It would maybe play 1 sec or so and then just hang. Moving the mouse sometimes plays a few more frames. It's somewhat strange.

I thought this is a problem with my graphics somehow (also because it noticed the problem since a Nvidia graphics driver update, and I had other graphics problems before, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236721/desktop-hung-up-freeze-gpuwatchdog-segfault-nvidia-frontend-close)).

I thought this is an issue with Chrome but Firefox has the same problem.
Also disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome or doing sth like that did not help.

But then I switched the audio (I attached some Bluetooth headset), and suddenly all the videos play fine again, without any hang. So it was likely [the PulseAudio issue I described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307635/audio-device-got-stuck).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ubuntu & Zorin. but not with fedora. Recently tried out Wayland instead of the default option at the login screen and it sorted out the issue. Now the video plays without any shutter/Lag on chrome or chrome based browser

Comment: This isn't an acceptable answer here, telling someone to change distributions to fix an issue. A good answer will address the root of the problem and help the user both too understand the cause and to fix it.