# Audio device got stuck

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

```
Audio device got stuck!
```

This is the error message I get from Mplayer. But the problem is the same with all applications, when playing sound (which all use PulseAudio by default). I.e. I hear extreme stuttering, and it is mostly hanging. This also causes any videos to hang, e.g. YouTube video (thus my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306190/6878)).

This seems to be PulseAudio related. Because when I play via ALSA, it works fine. (I.e. disable the device in the PulseAudio controller, then use `mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=1.0 ...`.)

Also, the problem was not always there, but only occurred since some recent update.

Ubuntu 20.04.

Relevant audio devices (via `lspci -nn`):

```
09:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f9] (rev a1)
0b:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]
```

The second device is the device I want to use.

`head -n1 /proc/asound/card1/codec\#0`:

```
Codec: Realtek ALCS1200A
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm just experiencing similar audio problems, too.

I guess it is a problem, related to a recent update since it never happened before (1 to 2 weeks on Xubuntu 20.04 LTS) and will be fixed in a coming update. Until then, following command helped me to solve the problem for some hours without restart:

```
pulseaudio --kill
# the same as:
# pulseaudio -k
```

It takes 2 to 3 seconds for pulseaudio, which will restart automatically, and often the programs, doing audio, will work again without further intervention; sometimes I have to restart the affected programs (browser, vlc).

At least I don't have to logout or restart the computer, as YT-Videos often suggest.

I hope this helps and a real update fix will be provided soon.

Comment: I tried this as well, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related to sleep.

I tried this in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=2
```

Also `sudo alsa force-unload` together with `killall pulseaudio` (in a loop) until I finally unloaded all modules, and then reload via `sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel`.

Now it temporarily seems to work again.

---

After another restart, I had the problem again. Again, I did this loop:

```
$ while true; killall pulseaudio; sudo alsa force-unload; end
```

and after that succeeded after some iterations, I did:

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

That again fixed the problem.

I'm not sure if that `position_fix=2` is really relevant. But then I also don't really know what the real problem is.